# shell.NameSpace(path) returns null when path is a portable device's folder

Tags: c#, .net, shell32

I am trying to move files from one path to another, the destination path needs to support portable devices like android phones.

After discovering `FolderBrowserDialog` does not support portable devices I found [this](http://dev.flauschig.ch/wordpress/?p=212) blog that explains how to use `Shell32` and `COM-Objects`.

The problem is that I need to store the path (string) and load it back (from file) as `Folder` object, the method on doing so is to use the shell method `shell.NameSpace(path)`. 
That's only works with system paths, otherwise it will return null:

```
 shell = new Shell();
 Folder folder = shell.BrowseForFolder((int) Handle, "Select folder", 0, 0);
 Folder folderFromPath = shell.NameSpace((folder as Folder3).Self.Path);
 //folderFromPath is null if I choose android device folder.
```

While this works:

```
Folder folderFromPath = shell.NameSpace("C:\\Program Files");
 //folderFromPath is not null
```

Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently my android device generate this path:
`::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_2717&pid_ff40#329682240804#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,,54091657216}\{46DD6D4D-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`

Passing this path to shell.NameSpace method didn't work, but for some unknown reason 
removing `SID-{10001,,54091657216}` part made it work.

I really don't know what this part mean (though it's the reference for the internal storage of the device), which devices generate it and moreover, why nobody else posted about.

But if anyone else comes across this, I hope this will help :).

Answer (score 0):

This [USB\VID_2717&PID_FF40](https://www.devicekb.com/en/hardware/usb-vendors/vid_2717-pid_ff40) refers to Mi/Redmi series (MTP) which means the devices is a Mobile Device and connected as Media Transfer Protocol (MTP). Now, if someone is trying to Copy using the **CopyHere** approach, he can resolve this. Therefore, instead of using simply moving data or using **MoveHere**, use CopyHere. Hope this will be added information as well :-)